# Macos: disallow apps to prevent sleep

Tags: macos, mac, sleep

I keep getting notifications on my phone that Whatsapp web is active when my computer is supposed to be sleeping. The same happens with spotify: if I pause a song instead of stopping it the mac doesn't sleep.

I found this problem reported many times but no definitive answer on how to stop it. For me to prevent sleeping should be a privilege that I grant apps, is there any way to stop any apps preventing the mac to sleep?

Comment: This is still a bug with Spotify 1.0.75.483.g7ff4a0dc on macOS 10.13.3. Even if the Spotify is stopped, not just paused, it is still listed as prevent sleep in the Energy tab in Activity Monitor.

Comment: For Spotify, I made a fix here: https://silviustroe.com/spotify-prevents-macos-to-sleep-2020-fix/